# How to scan Azure MariaDB in Microsoft Purview

Tags: azure-purview

Microsoft Purview supports resources of type Azure Database for MySQL.
I have an Azure Database for MariaDB (which is also a flavor mySQL) but it seems that I can't register it as a source.
Is there a way to register and scan Azure Database for MariaDB resources?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Azure Purview does not support Azure Maria DB as a data source (as of 8/22). Hopefully, they will support it soon.
Until then the following python code which scans a Maria DB server and returns a collection of Atlas entities for the databases, tables, and columns could be useful.

```
from mysql.connector import errorcode
from pyapacheatlas.auth import ServicePrincipalAuthentication
from pyapacheatlas.core import PurviewClient
from pyapacheatlas.core import AtlasEntity, AtlasProcess
from pyapacheatlas.core import AtlasAttributeDef, EntityTypeDef, RelationshipTypeDef
from pyapacheatlas.core.util import GuidTracker
from mysql.connector import errorcode
import mysql.connector

def createMariaDbEntities(gt, dbConnParams, serverUri, serverName):

mariaSeverEntity = AtlasEntity(
    name=serverName,
    typeName="azure_mariadb_server",        
    qualified_name=serverUri,
    guid=gt.get_guid()
)

entities = []
entities.append(mariaSeverEntity)

try:
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(**dbConnParams)
    #print("Connection established")
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print("Something is wrong with the user name or password")
    elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        print("Database does not exist")
    else:
        print(err)
else:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    # find all databases
    enumerateDatabasesQuery = "show databases"
    cursor.execute(enumerateDatabasesQuery)
    res = cursor.fetchall()
    databases = [r[0] for r in res if r[0][0].isnumeric()]

    for (db) in databases:

        # find all the tables in the database
        readTablesQuery = "SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `{0}`;".format(db)
        cursor.execute(readTablesQuery)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        tables = [row[0] for row in rows if int(row[4]) > 0]
        if (len(tables) > 0):
            #print("datebase:", db)
            dbEntity = AtlasEntity(
                name=db,
                typeName="azure_mariadb_db",
                qualified_name="{0}/{1}".format(serverUri, db),
                guid=gt.get_guid(),
                server=mariaSeverEntity
            )
            entities.append(dbEntity)

            for table in tables:
                # print("Table:",table)
                tableEntity = AtlasEntity(
                    name=table,
                    typeName="azure_mariadb_table",
                    qualified_name="{0}/{1}/{2}".format(serverUri, db, table),
                    guid=gt.get_guid(),
                    db=dbEntity
                )
                entities.append(tableEntity)
                # find all the columns in the table
                columnsQuery = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM `{0}`.`{1}`;".format(db, table)
                cursor.execute(columnsQuery)
                rows = cursor.fetchall()                    
                columns = [(row[0], row[1]) for row in rows]
                for column in columns:
                    # print("Column:",column)
                    columnEntity = AtlasEntity(
                        name=column[0],                           
                        attributes={
                            "dataType": column[1]                               
                        },
                        typeName="azure_mariadb_table_column",
                        qualified_name="{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}".format(serverUri, db, table, column[0]),
                        guid=gt.get_guid()                           
                    )
                    columnEntity.addRelationship(table=tableEntity)
                    entities.append(columnEntity) 

# Cleanup
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()

return entities
```